# Изменение настроек виджета RadioButtons в matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, radiobutton

В своём коде я строю графики. Графиков много. Для переключения между графиками я использую RadioButtons. Расположение переключателей задаю кодом:

rax = plt.axes([0.905, 0.545, 0.09, 0.45], facecolor='yellow')

radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('SBX', 'SBIX', 'DCPKU1', 'DCPKU2', 'SSKPT', 'SSKHA', 'SOC', 'SOO1', 'SOCU','DCK', 'PUPK', 'SOP1.1', 'SOU', 'SOFU1', 'SOFU2', 'SOFU3', 'SOFU4', 'SOFU5','DCR', 'DCZ2','DCZ1', 'SOP1', 'SSKU', 'SOF', 'SBXM', 'CTO'))

Когда кнопок не много (5...6), то они отображаются красиво и эстетично. Но когда их много, "кружки" кнопок сжимаются до размера точек. Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу настроить размеры панели и размеры кнопок. Чтение Tutorials по matplotliby ничего не дало. Буду очень рад помощи. Спасибо!
[image: Вид кнопок]

Answer (score 1):

На просторах англоязычного https://stackoverflow.com/ нашёл интересный вариант решения. Адаптировал под свои нужды. Может быть кому-то пригодится или "доработает" под лучший результат.

class MyRadioButtons(RadioButtons):

```
def __init__(self, ax, labels, active=0, activecolor='blue', size=80, orientation="vertical", **kwargs):
    AxesWidget.__init__(self, ax)
    self.activecolor = activecolor
    axcolor = ax.get_facecolor()
    self.value_selected = None
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_navigate(False)

    circles = []
    for i, label in enumerate(labels):
        if i == active:
            self.value_selected = label
            facecolor = activecolor
        else:
            facecolor = axcolor
        p = ax.scatter([],[], s=size, marker="o", edgecolor='black', facecolor=facecolor)
        circles.append(p)

    if orientation == "horizontal":
        kwargs.update(ncol=len(labels), mode="expand")
    kwargs.setdefault("frameon", False)    
    self.box = ax.legend(circles, labels, **kwargs)
    self.labels = self.box.texts
    self.circles = self.box.legendHandles
    for c in self.circles:
        c.set_picker(5)
    self.cnt = 0
    self.observers = {}
    self.connect_event('pick_event', self._clicked)

def _clicked(self, event):
    if (self.ignore(event) or event.mouseevent.button != 1 or
        event.mouseevent.inaxes != self.ax):
        return
    if event.artist in self.circles:
        self.set_active(self.circles.index(event.artist))
```

А пока у меня вот:
[image: RadioButtons]